# Custom UITableViewCell using storyboard with some cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have a TableView in which a most cells are pretty standard. I make them buy using static cells in Storyboard. However, one cell I would like to customize probably using an XIB file so I would need to load it programmatically.

In the TableView's data source, is it possible to handle loading XIB view for this particular cell only, while leaving other cells to what's delineated in the static cells in the Storyboard? Or is it an all or nothing thing where I need to just give up using static cells altogether?

The rationality for doing this is that I would like to make Storyboard to look as close to the real thing as possible. Right now if I provide a data source, the static cells in the storyboard would have no effect on the actual output and is not in any sense linked to the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Set the custom class for the custom cell. If you wish to customise it from code, just connect it as an IBOutlet to the UITableViewController.

[image: Cell Custom class]

Comment: Oh it's far simpler than I thought then, thanks. I guess I don't need to use other data source then.